# Memo1.Loadfromfile() space

Tags: delphi, text

How do I keep the same spaces that exist in the file .txt? In .txt file it says:

```
text     :text
text1    :text1
text23   :text2
text345  :text3
```

if I write this code:

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('Text.txt');
```

this appears in the Memo1:

```
text     :text
text1     :text1
text23     :text2
text345     :text3
```

the text is different from the file. txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a propotional Font like Courier.
Or better format your text with TAB.

Answer (score 6):

The file will be loaded faithfully. All whitespace is preserved exactly as it is in the file.

The most plausible explanation for what you observe is that your text editor displays the file differently from how the TMemo control displays it. Possibly your file contains tab characters. These are often displayed differently in different viewers. Or perhaps the text editor uses a monospace font, and your memo control does not.

But I stress again, the file will be loaded faithfully. The contents of the file are loaded into the memo control without alteration.